# Conditional expectation and random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X, Y$ be independent Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p$. Let $A=\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega)+Y(\omega) = 0\}$. How does one compute $E[X\cdot\mathbb{1}_{A^{c}}]$? My guess is that since $X$ can be both $0$ and $1$ and the sum could still be bigger than $0$, the result is simply $0\cdot(1-p)+1\cdot p=p$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $X \cdot 1_{A^c}$ takes on values in $\{0,1\}$, so $\mathbb{E}X1_{A^c} = \mathbb{P}[ X1_{A^c} = 1 ]$. The latter event holds iff $X=1$ and $X+Y > 0$. If $X=1$ then $X+Y >0$ always, so that
$$ \mathbb{P}[ X1_{A^c} = 1 ] = \mathbb{P}[ X = 1 \wedge X+Y >0 ] = \mathbb{P}[X+Y>0 | X=1] \cdot \mathbb{P}[X=1] = \mathbb{P}[X=1] =p.  $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\mathbb E[X\boldsymbol 1_{A^c}]=\mathbb E[X]-\mathbb E[X\boldsymbol 1_A]$$

and $$\mathbb E[X\boldsymbol 1_A]=\mathbb P\{X=1,X+Y=0\}=0.$$